# In Apache Solr, is there a way to determine whether a core has any uncommitted/staged changes?

Tags: solr

I would like to implement a more rigorous transaction/concurrency model in my client than Solr itself implements. One key piece to this is determining whether there are any uncommitted/staged changes in a core in Solr. Is there a request I can make to Solr from a client to figure this out?

Comment: Maybe it helps to get in touch with the Solr community and find out on what they are working on. To me it doesn't sound like an Solr / git specific question. At least not solvable this way.

Comment: Thanks @david. I might contact the community directly. This doesn't have anything to do with git; it's about data being staged, that is, ready to be indexed into a Solr core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the metrics API - [the `UPDATE.updateHandler` segment](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/performance-statistics-reference.html#update-handler) will have the `docsPending` value set:

> UPDATE.updateHandler.docsPending: Number of documents which are pending commit.

There's also the `adds` stats:

> UPDATE.updateHandler.adds: Total number of “add” requests since last commit.

These stats are available per core.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh - `docsPending`, along with `deletesById` and `deletesByQuery` should get me exactly what I need!